# Android app is supported by 0 devices in Play Store Publish

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

We don't understand why after the upload of our apk on the Google Play Developer Console we have 0 devices supported. Our personal thought is the Manifest and the build.gradle are ok: we can produce apk, than we can distribuite it to our beta tester without problems. Can you help us? Where is our error here, in your opinion?

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.hendyghsta.bacameter"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:name=".common.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.TesterActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ScanActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ResultActivity"
            android:label="Input Result"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="Pembaca Meter"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SettingActivity"
            android:label="Pengaturan"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.afollestad.materialcamera.CaptureActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialCamera.CaptureActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.afollestad.materialcamera.CaptureActivity2"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialCamera.CaptureActivity"/>

        <service
            android:name=".common.UploadService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LogActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="***"/>

        <service android:name=".account.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".account.FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".activity.PesanActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.BarcodeActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".common.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

App **Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hendyghsta.bacameter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "3.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Acer/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        //exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'

//        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/librealm-jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/librealm-jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/librealm-jni.so'

        exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_java3.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libanylineCore.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so'
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile(name: 'anylinesdk-3.8.1', ext: 'aar')
    compile project(':mcamera')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.14@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.1.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice-ftp:3.2.3'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.robinhood.ticker:ticker:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try test the features required by your application - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing and post the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with location:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Acctording to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission):

> Caution: If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher, you must declare that your app uses the android.hardware.location.network or android.hardware.location.gps hardware feature in the manifest file, depending on whether your app receives location updates from NETWORK_PROVIDER or from GPS_PROVIDER. If your app receives location information from either of these location provider sources, you need to declare that the app uses these hardware features in your app manifest. On devices running verions prior to Android 5.0 (API 21), requesting the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission includes an implied request for location hardware features. However, requesting those permissions does not automatically request location hardware features on Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher.

So add

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove uses-sdk tag from Manifest too. Try to upload another version.

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>
```

There can be problem with Google Developer console too. They are updating the system. You may try new App App release, try to create a ALPHA release.

Comment: This will not fix the problem. These values will be added by the android gradle plugin when it does manifest merging.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Thank you for clarification :)